# Как открыть стороннее приложение из своего приложения?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно использовать стороннее приложение в своем проекте(просмотр 3d моделей). Можно ли как то допустим при нажатии на кнопку в своем приложении открывать нужное мне приложение? Может как то программно запускать его исполняющий файл?

Comment: Нет - недаром же система устроена как набор слабовзаимодействующих песочниц. Если приложение(какой-либо его компонент) "хочет", чтобы его запускали извне, оно явно об этом "говорит" в своем манифесте - какие интенты оно принимает. Да и на уровне Android вообще нет такого понятия как "исполняемый файл".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге я сделал это так

```
public void reeee(View view) {
    String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo/files/default/AvatarModelDir/Anna.dae";
    File file = new File(path);

    //checking if the File exists
    if(file.exists()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/octet-stream");

        boolean result = isIntentAvailable(getApplicationContext(), intent);

        if (result){
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return !list.isEmpty();
}
```

Указывая путь к файлу который нужно открыть и правильный тип MIME (в моем случае это `application/octet-stream`) у меня все работает

Comment: В релизной версии цикл из метода `isIntentAvailable()` видимо, лучше всего исключить, так как для пользователя он не несет ничего, кроме бесполезного для него потребления ресурсов.

Comment: @pavlofff вы имеете ввиду сразу делать `startActivity()` ? А что если нет ни одного приложения которое может открыть этот файл? Так то у меня проверка есть...

Comment: Не саму, проверку, а непосредственно цикл `for` в ней, который не делает ничего, кроме как выводит содержимое списка в лог, в пользовательской версии это лишнее, на мой взгляд

Comment: @pavlofff аа вы про это, да согласен. Это я просто для себя делал

Answer (score 5):

самостоятельно Вы приложение пользователя не запустите, это должен сделать он сам,но реализовать диалог выбора приложений, которые могут обработать Ваш запрос вы можете при помощи неявного intent. Таким образом, сделать запрос на запуск стороннего приложения Вы сможете. Но важно, чтобы приложение,которое Вы хотите запустить явно уведомляло Андроид , посредством своего манифеста,о том, что его можно запускать из вне.

Comment: А как я могу проверить есть ли это уведомление в его манифесте? У меня ж нет кода этого приложения...

Comment: можно воспользоваться методом queryIntentActivities(). Он Вам вернет список активити, которые могут обработать Ваш запрос.

Answer (score 1):

Запустить чужой пакет из своего приложения просто

```
Intent intent = getContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("имя пакета");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: А как настроить манифест а то не открывается сторонке приложение?

Comment: Там от манифеста не зависит